# Android application audio recording on emulator but not on Samsung

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I am using a MediaRecorder to create a recording.

Believe it or not, this works on the emulator, but when I run it from my Samsung Galaxy S2, it does not record (or if it does, it does not play back!)

(Seems like the opposite problem from what others have been reporting - where the emulator doesn't work)

How can I diagnose this and fix it?

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(path.getAbsolutePath());
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

Comment: As for diagnosis, is there anything in LogCat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it -

```
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/mnt/sdcard/audio.amr");
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be relevant what your `path` is. Do make sure any directories are created beforehand, and the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is set.